# jQuery hover to swap images not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with a simple hover effect to change the image; does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I know it's simple, but I am new to JS.

```js
// Category hover effects
$(".category-switch span").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
}, function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">image 1</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 1 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">imag 2</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 2 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">image 3</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 3 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Your selector `.category-switch a span` don't match with your HTML code, you don't have any `a` element.

Comment: $(".category-switch a span") ....  here is your problem..  JS can not find selector you mention

Comment: Oh sorry i did not put in the example, let me fix that now and update the code.

Comment: Is it normal that the `span` are actually `display: none;` by default? You can't hover an element if it's set as `display: none;`. You can if it's just an `opacity: 0;`. If you want to keep that solution, you should apply this `display: none` on the `img` and and in the **JS** have something like `$(this).children('img').fadeToggle();`.

Comment: I have updated the markup.

Comment: you can do this with css using `:hover`

Comment: With fading effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to remove `span` from your selector and make it just the anchor. Then you find the spans within that to do your toggling. It'll still need tweaking to make it a smooth transition but answers this question.

```js
$('.category-switch').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('span').fadeToggle();
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('span').fadeToggle();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">image 1</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 1 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">imag 2</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 2 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="category-switch">
            <span><img src="">image 3</span>
            <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 3 - hover</span>
        </a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

This is also achievable with pure CSS.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  00% {opacity: 0; display:block;}  
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0; display:block;}  
  100% {opacity: 1;}  
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1; display:block;}
  100% {opacity: 0; display:none;}  
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1; display:block;}
  100% {opacity: 0; display:none;}    
}
li .category-switch {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:50px;
  min-height:50px;
}
li .category-switch span {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.5s ease-in; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: fadeOut 0.5s ease-in;
}
li .category-switch span.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in;
}
li:hover .category-switch span.hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
li:hover .category-switch span:not(.hidden) {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="category-switch">
      <span><img src="">image 1</span>
      <span class="hidden"><img src="">image 1 - hover</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="category-switch">
      <span><img src="">imag 2</span>
      <span class="hidden"><img src="">image 2 - hover</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="category-switch">
      <span><img src="">image 3</span>
      <span class="hidden"><img src="">image 3 - hover</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @James Please see an edit for a pure CSS solution. Works better, and less overheads.

Comment: Thanks mate, i prefer css solutions however have a look http://2015.ambientlounge.com/interior/ hover over the Acoustic one on the left and the transition is not very smooth... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the "a" from the selector, or wrap the first instance of the span with an "a" tag within each "li" element.

Solution 1:

`$(".category-switch span").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
}, function () {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
});`

Solution 2:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="">image 1</span></a>
        <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 1 - hover</span>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"><span><img src="">imag 2</span></a>
    <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 2 - hover</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="">image 3</span></a>
        <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 3 - hover</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: That did not switch the image, just fade out the image and does not show the new one. i need to wrap both in the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some classes and changed the javascript a bit. I didn't get exactly the effect you want to achieve, but `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` from jquery may be better options. Try it out below.

```js
// Category hover effects
$(".category-switch span.hoverable").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).next('span').fadeIn();
});

   $(".category-switch").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('span.hoverable').fadeIn();
    $(this).find('span.hoverable').next('span').fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="category-switch">
        <span class='hoverable'><img src="">image 1</span>
        <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 1 - hover</span>
    </li>
    <li class="category-switch">
        <span class='hoverable'><img src="">image 2</span>
        <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 2 - hover</span>
    </li>
    <li class="category-switch">
        <span class='hoverable'><img src="">image 3</span>
        <span style="display:none;"><img src="">image 3 - hover</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Would that fade back to the original when you mouse out though? i did try the example but did not see, to work when i integrated it.

Comment: @James have a look at it now. The selected answer has a strange glitch.